# How to place radio button at each row in qtablewidget and allow only one row to select from group of rows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

Below is my table :

[image: Table]

In the above table, i have placed the Radiobutton at each row.

In the table, column 'field' has same values in the rows i.e startdate is present in two rows and validity is also repeating in rows. 
What i want is to only select only one  row consisting validity from the repeating values using radio button. if user selects another value,it must deselect previously selected value.

Below is my code:

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.data=data
        rows=len(data)

        data1=list()

        for d in data:
            #print d
            #print "ddddddddddddddd",type(d)

            d=d.replace('null','""')

            d=eval(d)

            #print type(d)
            data1.append(d)
        self.data1=data1
        key_list=['file','field','content','refined_content','page_number']
        data2=list()
        for line in data1:
            #print line
            d = OrderedDict((k, line[k]) for k in key_list)
            data2.append(d)
        #print data2
        data1=data2
        #print data1

        keys = ['file','field','content','refined_content','page_number']

        keys=list(keys)

        columns=len(keys)+1



        keys.append("checkbox")


        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(rows, columns, self)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(keys) 


        self.keys=keys
        #print "total columns",columns
        #print "total rows",rows
        #columns=str(columns)

        for column in range(columns-1):
            for row in range(rows):
                qwidget = QtGui.QWidget()


                checkbox = QtGui.QRadioButton()
                checkbox.setChecked(False)

                qhboxlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(qwidget)
                qhboxlayout.addWidget(checkbox)
                qhboxlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                qhboxlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                dic=data1[row]
                #print dic

                index=int(column)
                #print "index",index
                value = dic.values()[index]
                #print "current row",row
                #print "current column",column
                self.table.setItem(row, column, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(value)))
                #self.table.setItem(row, columns+1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(row)))
                self.table.setCellWidget(row,columns-1 , qwidget)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.button.setObjectName("loadButton")
        self.button.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.button.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.button.setStyleSheet('color: white;background-color:rgb(0, 76, 153);border-style: outset;border-width: 2px;border-color: rgb(0, 76, 153);border-radius: 10px;alignment:left;')

        self.button.setText("Submit")

        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.ButtonClicked)


    def ButtonClicked(self,c):
        c=self.table.columnCount()

        #print "c",c
        #print "keys",self.keys
        checked_list = []
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            #checked_list = []
            dic={}
            if self.table.cellWidget(i, c-1).findChild(type(QtGui.QRadioButton())).isChecked():
                for j in range(c-1):

                    st=str(self.table.item(i, j).text())
                    #print j,st
                    dic[self.keys[j]]=st
                    #checked_list.append(st)
                #print "ddiic",dic
                checked_list.append(dic)
        print checked_list
```

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: You can explain better, your description is confusing.

Comment: The column 'field' has value 'validity' in 7 rows for file 'Lease Aggrement'. I want to select only one at a time.

Comment: What do you mean  "select"? Do you mean that only one radiobutton is checked?

Comment: yes i want only one radiobutton to be checked for value 'validity'.

Comment: A query that column is editable?

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying

Comment: asked if the values shown under the field column will change after the table is displayed